# Change Slide on Button Click - react-slick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-slick

I am using `react slick` in my react project. I have `5 slides`, `one button(Go to Slide3)`, and `one text(Current Slide Number)` in my UI.
When I click the button, in the react-slick, it should move to the third slide. Whenever the slide change, I also want to set the current slide number. 
Here's the UI:

[image]

I tried but I don't know how to make it. I searched react-slick documentation but unable to find that how to change the slide on the outer button click. In Documentation, it shows functions for prev and next arrow click 
Here's the Code SandBox Link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slick-custom-arrows-and-dots-example-forked-1hq26c?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `slickGoTo` method.

This method accepts `index`, where you want to slide!

First, you have to create `ref` and pass it to the react-slick component, then you can access the methods provided by react-slick.

https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/api/#methods

Here is the example:

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";

import Slider, { slickGoTo } from "react-slick";
import { useState } from "react";

function Arrow(props) {
  let className = props.type === "next" ? "nextArrow" : "prevArrow";
  className += " arrow";
  const char = props.type === "next" ? "" : "";
  return (
    <span className={className} onClick={props.onClick}>
      {char}
    </span>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const sliderRef = useRef();

  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState("Slide 1");
  const slides = ["Slide 1", "Slide 2", "Slide 3", "Slide 4", "Slide 5"];
  const renderSlides = () =>
    slides.map((text) => (
      <div>
        <h3>{text}</h3>
      </div>
    ));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Slider
        nextArrow={<Arrow type="next" />}
        prevArrow={<Arrow type="prev" />}
        ref={sliderRef}
      >
        {renderSlides()}
      </Slider>

      <button
        style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}
        onClick={() => {
          setCurrentSlide("Slide 3");
          //Indexing starts from 0
          sliderRef.current.slickGoTo(2);
        }}
      >
        Goto Slide 3
      </button>
      <div style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>Current Slide : {currentSlide} </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you should use useRef and slickGoTo function. 
Example: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slick-custom-arrows-and-dots-example-forked-6bllre?file=/src/App.js

doc: https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/slick-go-to